# How to determine whether an improper integral is convergent or divergent using the comparison test

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Am I doing this question right using CT? Can anyone please help me out?

Determine whether this integral is convergent or divergent.

$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{3+sin(x)}{e^x}$

$3\ge sin(x)$ for all x $\in[1,\infty)$

$\frac{3}{e^x}\ge \frac{sin(x)}{e^x}$

$0\le \frac{3}{e^x}\le \frac{sin(x)}{e^x}$

Let f(x) = $\frac{3}{e^x}$
Let g(x) = $\frac{sin(x)}{e^x}$

Since $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{3}{e^x}$ converges, $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{sin(x)}{e^x}$ also converges, so therefore, $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{3+sin(x)}{e^x}$ converges

Answer (score 1):

That is not true because $\sin x$ could be negative for certain $x\in[1,\infty)$.

Rather, $\left|\dfrac{3+\sin x}{e^{x}}\right|\leq\dfrac{3+|\sin x|}{e^{x}}\leq\dfrac{4}{e^{x}}$ and we have $\displaystyle\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{4}{e^{x}}dx=4e^{-1}<\infty$, so $\displaystyle\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{3+\sin x}{e^{x}}dx$ converges absolutely.

In fact, $3+\sin x\geq 3-1=2>0$, so $\dfrac{3+\sin x}{e^{x}}>0$ and the absolute convergence is simply the usual convergence.

Comment: where did 4 over $e^x$ come from?

Comment: $|\sin x|\leq 1$, so $3+|\sin x|\leq 3+1=4$.

Comment: Oh ok so whenever we have a trig function, we need to consider the absolute values?

Comment: It is hard to tell, but in this case I try absolute convergence and I succeed, of course, not every improper integral converges absolutely, take for example $\displaystyle\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sin x}{x}dx$, if we take absolute value, then we mess up.

Comment: So when do we use the absolute value?

Comment: Provided that you have the confidence that the majoring function is absolutely convergent.

Comment: What if we are not confident it's absolutely convergent?

Comment: Then don't use that, just like that one $\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ won't succeed in doing so. Actually $e^{-x}$ is integrable, so we use absolute value in the question.

Comment: So how would we do this question without the absolute value?

Comment: Actually without absolute value, it might need to recourse to complex analysis method. Anyway, for $\dfrac{\sin x}{e^{x}}$, if we put absolute value, it is less than or equal to $\dfrac{1}{e^{x}}$ which is integrable. Of course, most of the time we need to use absolute value, but not right immediate. Just that $\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$, a typical method is to use integration by parts first, and then for $-\dfrac{\cos x}{x^{2}}$ we now use absolute value to end up with $\dfrac{1}{x^{2}}$, which is convergent on $[1,\infty)$.

Comment: Can we just break up the integral into two parts and then integrate it normally instead of using CT?

Comment: So you want to deal with $e^{-x}$ and $\sin x/e^{x}$ separately. Yes, of course, in this case you can because that $\sin x/e^{x}$ is also convergent. The thing is, what do you mean by integrate it normally? I am not sure how to do elementary integration to figure out the integral of $\sin x/e^{x}$. One uses complex analysis to go through.

Comment: You use integration by parts don't you?

Comment: For that $\sin x/x$, yes, one goes through with integration by parts, but that does not compute the exact value of the integral and it hard to use real analysis to compute the exact value, but if we just want to determine if it is convergent, then it helps, and one uses absolute convergence for $-\cos x/x^{2}$.

Comment: I mean can we do integration by parts for $sin(x)/e^x$ and integrate 3 over $e^x$ normally?

Comment: This is the thing I cannot understand, if you do integration by parts to $\sin x/e^{x}$, then you will end up with another integral like $\cos x/e^{x}$, I don't see why one can then easily integrate $\cos/e^{x}$.

Comment: Ah... I think you messed up with the terminology that I used, it is not integration by parts, what you intended to say was, as I guessed, splitting the integral as the sum of two integrals. And yes, you can split in this case, because the integrals of both $1/e^{x}$ and $\sin x/e^{x}$ are convergent.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant, splitting the integral as the sum of two integrals and then finding the integral of $3/e^x$ and $sinx/e^x$.

Comment: Just curious, how would this question change if it was e to the negative x instead of e to the x?

Comment: Then it is definitely no good: $\displaystyle\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{x}dx=\infty$.

Comment: So if it was e to the negative x, then the whole thing would diverge because 4 over e to the negative x goes to infinity?